# How to prevent renderUI from printing results in the console

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am developing a shiny app and frequently use the `dput(names(data))` in the `renderUI`. Because of it, I see the output of `dput(names(data))` on the console.

How to prevent `dput` showing the output in the console?

Thank you.

D

Comment: Either comment it out or use something like `logger::log_debug` where your normal logging threshold is above (less-terse than) `logger::DEBUG`. By selective use of `logger::log_threshold`, you can allow or prevent its printing on the console regardless of in-`shiny` or out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is not clear how can I do that. Trying ```logger::log_debug(dput(names(data)))``` did not solve the issue.

Comment: Try this: when "playing", use `logger::log_threshold(logger::DEBUG)`. But in "production" (i.e., when you do not want to see the output from `dput`), use `logger::log_threshold(logger::INFO)`.

Comment: I apologize, but I am not able to get it right. I followed your advice, but yet I see the output of ```dput()``` on the console. To clarify, I am developing a ```shinydashboard```.

Comment: If you set `log_threshold(INFO)` then anything logged with `log_debug` will be silent/unobserved. If you still see it, then you are doing something else wrong. This question is nearly impossible to help much further without details. If you need more help, please read how to provide a good reproducible question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Not sure what you want. What about `capture.output(dput(names(data))`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ```capture.output()``` suppresses the output in the console, but then have an issue with ```selectizeInput``` which shows in the drop-down menu ```c("var1","var2)``` instead of ```var1```, ```var2```.

Comment: @JohnS Please provide some code. We dont' know what you're doing and we have to guess. What about `toString(names(data))`? If that does not work, please provide a minimal reproducible example and explain what you want exactly.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thanks! Yes, I have to make a small reproduce example. Sorry for the inconvenience. ```toString()``` and  ```capture.output()``` does not solve the issue.